# How to pass data from client to server in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

Could you please provide any suggestion to build logic for below scenario??

**Progress:**

I have one data extension which has three columns:

1. City
2. Area
3. Center.

I have created landing page which has the three picklist fields listed above.

in first picklist i have populated the distinct values from City

**Challange:**

First only city picklist is visible and the other two picklists should be  disabled.

When the user selects any value from city picklist, then it should give call to marketing cloud server with selected city parameter before allowing the user to click the submit button.

The server will search the Area column of data extension, using passed City value and return the matched area values under particular city to new Picklist

**I need help on two topics:**

How this logic should be implemented - Meaning should call be made before clicking on submit button? Meaning when user select the value from picklist.

I haven't came across this server client scenario. I have seen some examples where RequestParameter() is used, but i don't exactly where should i write this logic. Should i create two landing page one for form and one two handle server logic?

Please explain with some steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two routes to go with this:

**Javascript:**

1. Using [SSJS pull a JSON](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/rows/lookup/) of your values from the DE
2. [Pass the JSON to the Client side](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/) - will need to [Stringify](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/utilities_server_side_javascript_functions/string_utility_functions/stringify/).
3. Using Javascript or JQuery, you will need to parse through the JSON and have the picklists activate/fill based on user actions. ([sample from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453677/selecting-a-value-from-drop-down-changes-the-next-drop-down-list))

**AMPScript:** (Will require multiple LPS)

4. Using [LookupOrderedRows()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) or similar - pull the unique City values from your DE
5. Use [Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm) and [Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm) to get specific values via a FOR loop.
6. Fill in your picklist (potentially using [BuildOptionList()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildoptionlist.htm).
7. Create a LP with AMPScript to display content based on passed parameters e.g. `%%[IF @submitCity == 1 THEN]%% City Picklist content %%[ELSEIF @submitArea == 1 THEN]%% Area Picklist content %%[ELSEIF @submitCenter == 1 THEN]%% Center picklist content %%[ELSE]%% Default content %%[ENDIF]%%`
8. Have the LP post to itself using a hidden field on each dynamic area to show the iteration - e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="submitCenter" value="1" />`.
9. Using [RequestParameter()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) to collect the values posted and use those to do a lookup to fill in the next picklist from the previous response.

I personally recommend the Javascript solution as although it is difficult for those not familiar with JS, it will not require 3+ page impressions for each form filled out.  It also is a bit less complex and will likely require less maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for your help..  I am working on the second (AMP Script solution) but I would like to prefer first one because i already worked on JS. Could you please provide any sample code or any link which would help me?

Comment: The sample from my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453677/selecting-a-value-from-drop-down-changes-the-next-drop-down-list) should help with the javascript portion

Comment: Thanks!!....   I have used jquery in visualforce pages but not in marketing cloud. First I need to download jquery zip file and upload in portfolio. Right?? Could you please help me with some starting points?? I will do the rest..

Comment: You can use cdn or store in portfolio for jquery. Outside that it is same as normal webpage or VF page

Comment: @ Gortonington  Thanks.... !! I am able to use Jquery. As per your suggestion I have retrieved data from  DE using SSJS. Now I want to pass it to client side. I don't know how to do this. Could you please suggest?? just give any useful link

Comment: In the above link referencing passing it has this info. It is about halfway down the page. The tag begins with something like `<ctrl:var name=yourvar />`